# Cannot find an overload for "XmlMessageFormatter" and the argument count: N in Powershell with New-Object

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I can't seem to get the `New-Object` function in Powershell 2.0 to use the correct constructor for the type `XmlMessageFormatter`.

The MS documentation for `XmlMessageFormatter` is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.xmlmessageformatter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Messaging_XmlMessageFormatter__ctor_System_Type___

I want to use the constructor that takes an array of types:

```
XmlMessageFormatter(Type[] targetTypes);
```

My powershell script looks like this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging")
$queue = New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue $queuePath
[Type[]]$types = [MyNamespace.MyClass1], [MyNamespace.MyClass2], [MyNamespace.MyClass3]
$queue.Formatter = New-Object System.Messaging.XmlMessageFormatter($types);
```

To re-create the issue you can probably use this code:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging")
[Type[]]$types = [System.String], [System.Int], [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]
$formatter = New-Object System.Messaging.XmlMessageFormatter($types);
```

I was reading about arrays in PowerShell here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7

The error message seems to think I am sending multiple arguments rather than a single argument of an array:

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "XmlMessageFormatter" and the argument count: "3".
At C:\temp\test.ps1:20 char:20
+ $queue.Formatter = New-Object System.Messaging.XmlMessageFormatter($types);
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Comment: Change `New-Object System.Messaging.XmlMessageFormatter($types)` to `New-Object System.Messaging.XmlMessageFormatter @(,$types)`

Comment: That worked! how weird, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell assumes that you're passing it an array of 3 *individual parameter arguments* for the `XmlMessageFormatter` constructor, hence the `... with the argument count: "3".` part of the error message.

Use the `,` unary array operator to wrap the `$types` array in yet another array, so that PowerShell will treat `$types` as a single parameter argument when invoking the constructor:

```bsh
New-Object System.Messaging.XmlMessageFormatter (,$types)
```